# For what do you need to change hardwareclock and how?

Tags: linux, timezone, clock

I started Linux server (Amazon Linux 2) from scratch.
I'm in Tokyo locale and I changed timezone info like this;

```
ll /etc/localtime
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Feb 22 10:11 /etc/localtime -> ../usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC

# backup
sudo cp -p /etc/localtime /etc/localtime.org

# change timezone
sudo ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo /etc/localtime

ll /etc/localtime
# lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 30 Mar 10 22:06 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Tokyo
```

Now the followings have been affected, being 9 hours ahead of UTC, which seems sufficient to me.

- the result of 'date' command
- the execution time of cron jobs
- the logging time of daemons

However, I googled and found that some articles suggest you should also make changes to the hardware clock.

```
# default    
cat /etc/sysconfig/clock
# ZONE="UTC"
# UTC=true
```

Is it better to modify this file?
If so, how? and what will be affected?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The articles you found are "wrong". By usual convention on Linux systems, you leave the hardware clock in a unified time zone (i.e., UTC), and the software converts the hardware time to a local time zone as needed.

The `"` around "wrong" are just because that's only a convention. You can do it otherwise, but it has no advantages. On the contrary, if you set it to a local time zone, the hardware clock would have to do things like follow daylight savings time. That's not what you want, usually, because that would mean you'd need to change the hardware clock twice a year.

So, yeah. Keep the system clock in UTC. I don't know about AWS, but it's not rare that a VM can't even change the actual time supplied by the hardware clock.

Comment: Tokyo doesn't have daylight savings, so no problem on that account

Answer (score 0):

Not amazon specific.  I strongly suspect that amazon's hardware clocks are correct and you should just deal with the local OS timezone. However, I am providing all of the information for the true (or emulated) hardware clock.

1. Find out what time it is in UTC in the real world (if you are not sure: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc)
2. Validate what clock your hardware thinks it is: `sudo TZ=UTC hwclock --get`
3. Check what your OS thinks the time is, in UTC:  `date -u`

The times in steps 1, 2, and 3 should agree with each other.  If OS is wrong (step 3), then `ntpdate pool.ntp.org`. If hwclock is wrong (step 2), then `sudo TZ=UTC hwclock -w -u`  (Whether EC2's emulated hardware clock will let you change it is an interesting question--amazingly it does).

Now you can check to see which timezone your hardware clock is in.

4. Check your hardware clock as if the hardware timezone is UTC: `sudo TZ=UTC hwclock -u --get`

If that returns the approximate real UTC clock, then your hardware clock is using UTC.  If it returns a different value, you are using a timezone in the local clock.  My bias, this is never a good idea, but perhaps some third party OS disagree (if you are dual-booting, unlikely on EC2).

Now finally, you are prepared to set the OS's timezone, so that when you look at logs you can understand when they actually happened.  You could choose UTC and have a common world-wide time for highest sanity.  You could choose the timezone local to the server, which makes logs from other availability zones require conversion prior to comparison.  You could choose the timezone you are in (and annoy your co-workers in other locations).  In the example command below, I selected UTC.

`ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime`

At this point, `date` should print the time in whatever timezone you selected.

/etc/sysconfig/clock was a way to have that symlink (from /etc/localtime) be recreated on boot, but I think most OS providers have since thought better and no longer do this.  I recommend not using /etc/sysconfig/clock or if it exists, making sure it is set correctly and after a reboot, checking that /etc/localtime still is set correctly.

Answer (score -3):

At some point you will communicate with servers outside of your machine, and at that point you will often have to agree with them about the time. That may be just to avoid confusion, but often for security reasons to avoid replay attacks. So your computer should know what the time is in UTC, or there is a good chance you have trouble.

Your hardware clock should reflect as good as it can what the time really is. If we compare our hardware clocks, and you are in London and I'm in Los Angeles, our hardware clocks should be identical. Our local time obviously would be different.

Comment: Your distributed computers do not compare hardware clocks, at all. This is all software, and to the distaste running on your Linux it doesn't matter to which time zone the hardware is set, as long as it knows, and accounts for that. You *can* do that perfectly well with non-utc hardware time. So, I'm afraid your answer is misleading and wrong!